# How to create api for download products in sqlite format

Tags: magento-1.7

How to create API for download products in sqlite format in magento.

I want to make view of database table to get some information and convert it into sqlite.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this function in my custom magneto API.  It will generate the sqlite db with selected product columns. you can use it with your magento and set path accordingly.
I am feeling happy to share this here. If you can improve or want to suggest to me with my code then you are welcome.

Thanks to all in advance.

/***
        ** function to Creating sqlite db of products 
        *
        ***/

```
public function sqlitedb()
    {
        $root= dirname(Mage::getRoot());
        $path=$root.'/marcodeappdb';
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }            
        unlink( $path.'/marcodeapp.zip');
        $database = new sqlite3($path.'/marcodeapp.sqlite');    

        $query = 'CREATE TABLE Products '.'(Sku TEXT, Name TEXT, Price INTEGER,ShortD TEXT,Description TEXT,Image TEXT,Categories TEXT)';
        $database->exec($query);

          $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
          $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
          //pr($collection);
         foreach($collection as $product){
                $sku=$product->sku;
                $name=$product->getName();  
                $price=$product->getPrice();
                $shortd=$product->getDescription();
                $description=$product->getDescription();
                $image=$product->getImageUrl();
                //categoryids
                $catids=$product->getCategoryIds();
                $productcatname=array();
                foreach($catids as $catid){
                        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
                    $productcatname[]=$category->getName();

                }
                $productcate=implode(',',$productcatname);  

            $query ="INSERT INTO Products (Sku, Name, Price,ShortD,Description,Image,Categories) VALUES ('$sku', '$name', '$price','$shortd','$description','$image','$productcate');";
            $database->exec($query);
            unset($query);
            unset($sku);
            unset($name);unset($price);unset($shortd);unset($description);unset($image);
            unset($productcate);unset($productcatname);
          }
        $database->close(); 

        $files_to_zip = array($path.'/marcodeapp.sqlite');      
        $result = $this->create_zip($files_to_zip,$path.'/marcodeapp.zip');
        unlink( $path.'/marcodeapp.sqlite');

        return 'http://mercode.com.br/MERCODE/marcodeappdb/marcodeapp.zip';         
    }
```